# Symfony date variable if statement

Tags: php, date, if-statement, symfony-1.4

I have 2 variables being set like this:

```
      <?php $current = strftime('%m/%d/%g %H:%M:%S')?>
      <?php $target = strftime('%m/%d/%g %H:%M:%S', strtotime($item->getendtime()))?>
```

Then I have an if statement like this:

```
      <?php if ($current < $target): ?>
         Do this
      <?php else: ?>
         Do that
      <?php endif; ?>
```

It works fine until we are in a new year.   For example, I have a few items that have an "endtime" in 2012.   If the if statement works as it should, it should "DO THAT" but instead it's doing "DO THIS"

Comment: If you using Doctrine and php >= 5.3 you can compare dates like this: `new DateTime() < $item->getDateTimeObject('end_time')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below instead (compare with the unix timestamp):

```
$current = time();
$target = strtotime($item->getendtime());
```

Comment: If I try that without using "strftime" then the $current string returns a large integer.  The $item->getendtime() is stored in the database as a date, not an integer.

Comment: That's why you use the `strtotime` function which changes your date from database into this large integer (the UNIX timestamp).

Comment: Worked great.   Thank you for this.